# Remove empty arrays with empty values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter

Right to the point. I have a form that submits a multidimensional array of values. Usually it gets something like this.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [socialClass] => Myclass
        [socialLink] => http://...
        [socialName] => Name
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [socialClass] => 
        [socialLink] => MyClass
        [socialName] => Name
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [socialClass] => 
        [socialLink] => 
        [socialName] => 
    )
```

The idea es to remove incomplete arrays from the tree, like `[1]` and `[2]`, so i would return like this after the *filter*.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [socialClass] => Class
        [socialLink] => http://...
        [socialName] => Name
    )
```

`array_filter` doesn't work in this case, and other "recursive" custom made functions either. How can I do it?

Comment: Actually, array_filter works very well in this case.

Comment: Tried, didnt work. So many answers! Im gonna test them all, and post results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) call with a custom filter function should do the trick for you:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($sub_arr) {
    foreach ($sub_arr as $item)
        if ($item === "")
            return false;
    return true;
});
```

You'll note that the item will be removed if any of its sub-array values is the empty string.

Comment: Yes, this works. The end result is "Array ()", so I only had to add "if (empty($arr)) unset $arr".

Answer (score 3):

For PHP >= 5.3

```
$myarray = array_filter($myarray, function ($node) {
    return count(array_filter($node)) == count($node);
});
```

Comment: This works too, at least for 1 level nesting - I'm using PHP 5.5, so it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Array filter would be great in this exact case:

```
$result = array_filter($input, function($a){
    return isset($a['socialClass']) 
           && isset($a['socialLink']) 
           && isset($a['socialName'])
           && !empty($a['socialClass']) 
           && !empty($a['socialLink']) 
           && !empty($a['socialName']);
});
```

This should work!

Comment: This will not work as expected if the array index exists but whose value is the empty string.